# Widget on the lock screen

Tags: java, android, widget, lockscreen

My application uses a widget which is perfectly displayed on the home screen. I have tried to have the widget displayed on the lock screen but, so far, nothing appears on it.

I have implemented all what is described in the documentation: widget category set to "keyguard|home_screen", initialKeyguardLayout property pointing to a specific xml file, check of the type of screen currently being displayed in the `onUpdate` function of my `appWidgetProvider` class by getting the app widget options and loading the layout in the `RemoteViews` according to the `AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_HOST_CATEGORY`. But the widget is still not displayed on the lock screen.

I can't see what I am missing.

My phone runs with Android 4.3

Comment: When you choose to add the app widget to the lock screen, is it showing up as an option? Are you able to add any other widgets to the lock screen? FWIW, here is a sample app widget that supports the lock screen: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppWidget/TwoOrThreeDice

Comment: Nothing happens on the lock screen with my code. The SMS application displays a widget on the lock screen when an unread SMS exists.

Comment: Either the SMS application is always displaying a widget on the lockscreen, one that you added, or that is not implemented via a lockscreen widget, but rather via a manufacturer-altered lockscreen.